# I need to fire adobe data layer when the pagination changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, adobe, analytics, google-datalayer

i need to fire/analytics code a pageLoad event whenever a user navigate to different page in the pagination. i

```
// pageLoad.js

export const PageLoad = () => {
  const URL = lowerCaseElement(window.location.href);
   const pageLoadObject = {
        event: "pageLoad",
        page: {
            URL,
        },
        user: {
            email: loginInfo?.email || null,
            loginStatus: loginInfo ? 'loggedin' : 'anonymous',
        }
    }
    console.log(pageLoadObject);
{
    "event": "pageLoad",
    "page": {
      
        "URL": "http://localhost:4502/content/my-account/my-list.html?page=2",
    },
    "user": {
        "loginType": "loggedin",
        "email": "kiranxxxxxx@gmail.com",
    }
}
    window.adobeDataLayer.push(pageLoadObject);
}

// pagination.js

import { paginationPageLoad } from '../PageLoad'

const Pagination = (props) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        paginationPageLoad();
    }, [currentPage]);
}
```

the currentPage is state which consists of page number, i need to fire the adobe.datalayer.push everytime the user navigates between pages. apparently is not working as excepted the event is not firing.

```
console.log("pageLoad", window.adobeDataLayer.find(
    (activity) => activity.event === 'pageLoad'
)); 

{
    "event": "pageLoad",
    "page": {
      
        "URL": "http://localhost:4502/content/my-account/my-list.html?page=1",
    },
    "user": {
        "loginType": "loggedin",
        "email": "kiranxxxxxxx4@gmail.com",
    }
}
```

when i watch the event the pageLoad event is same when the component renders. like for every navigation the url must be changing but it is same.

Comment: Looks like you're malforming your json. Debug your code properly. Show us the screenshot of what you actually push into the dataLayer.

Comment: @BNazaruk, hey can you check my edited code, the object i'm trying to push

Comment: The extra commas aren't very helpful there, but they shouldn't interfere with the object. Good, now show how your Launch config looks. Well or whatever TMS you use. I presume it's Launch cuz you've mentioned Adobe. In particular, your DL extension. Should be either Adobe Client Data Layer or the Datalayer Manager.

Comment: And make sure you're not using adblockers.